# Speeding up PostGIS query

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to do a spatial join on a PostGIS table that has a bunch of hexes and each hex has an ID. I have a separate table withs points in lats and longs and I want to know which hex each point belong in. For instance (points are made up)

```
 id     lat    long
 1     -83.1    24.5  
 2      55.9   -90.2
 3      16.7    23.4
```

to

```
id      lat     long   hexid
 1     -83.1    24.5     5
 2      55.9   -90.2    87
 3      16.7    23.4    23
```

The problem I have is that I have alot of points (over 100 million) and doing the spatial join is taking DAYS. I have broken the query up into special geographic regions and running them concurrently, but is there anything I can do to my query that will improve my performance? My query is below:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS select id, lat::double precision, long::double precision

ALTER TABLE newtable ADD Primary key (id);

SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','newtable','geom',4326,'POINT',2);﻿

UPDATE newtable SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(long, lat) ,4326);

ALTER TABLE newtable ADD COLUMN hexid numeric;

UPDATE newtable set hexid = hextable.hexid from hextable WHERE  ST_Within(newtable.geom, hextable.geom);
```

Comment: does the hex table have a spatial index?

Comment: I'm actually not sure. How can I check?

Comment: Using PGAdmin, expand your hex table properties, expand the Indexes node, and you should see something there with '..._geom_...' in the name - if you don't have a spatial index built, use some sql like: CREATE INDEX "hextable_geom_spindex"
  ON "hextable"
  USING gist
  (geom);

Comment: Gotcha so I found out that I don't have an index for the tables. What is the performance increase I can expect to get off of creating an index?

Comment: Huge! Go for it and see for yrself!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say you're lacking a spatial index on your point table.

To check, Using PGAdmin, expand your point table properties, expand the Indexes node, and you should see something there with '...*geom*...' in the name

If you don't have a spatial index built, use some sql like:

```
CREATE INDEX "pointtable_geom_spindex" ON "pointtable" USING gist (geom);
```

...and it probably wouldn't hurt to have an index on your hex table too...!

Comment: So do I need to have the index on the hex table and the new table or should I only have one? Would having two indexes be faster than one? (Sorry I'm new to this)

Comment: Changed my answer to state that you should definitely have one on your point table, but it won't hurt to have one on your hex's either...

Comment: Hrmm doing some research, I'm curious to know if the ```SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','newtable','geom',4326,'POINT',2);``` statement will already create the spatial index. Do you know?

Comment: I don't think so... http://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html but you can create it easily after with the SQL I gave above...

Comment: I believe using ST_Intersects or ST_Contains in the join condition is faster http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2008/10/postgis-performance-prepared-geometry.html

Comment: @plablo09 tack that on as an answer...!

Answer (score 3):

As mapBaker said, the most important issue is having a spatial index on your geometries.

But, that being said, using prepared geometries is also way faster as stated [here](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2008/10/postgis-performance-prepared-geometry.html). So, using `ST_Intersects` or `ST_Contains` in the join condition should speed up the query.

Comment: so if these prepared geometries are faster, would it make any substantial differences in the results I get from using ```ST_Within```?

Comment: In your case it would make no difference at all. Since all you want to know is if a given point lies inside a polygon, the result will be the same with any of the three realtionships. You would get different results if you where relating lines or polygons

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking at the documentation on spatial queries. Just for a reference, do you have any idea where I can find a more intuitive explanation of the ST functions?

Comment: Well, it may not be the most intuitive document, but it wouldn't hurt to read the [Simple Feature Acees specification](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfa) . It defines and explains all the standard (ST) functions.